# Remove only first character from the field if it is 0

Tags: sql

How to write sql query which will show values skipping first character if it is 0 (only the first character). All values are 3 characters long.
Examples:

```
numbers
123
023
003
102
```

should display as follows (after executing the query)

```
numbers
123
23
03
102
```

I used the following solution, but it removes all 0's, not just the first. How to fix it so that it only removes the first character if it is 0.

```
SUBSTRING(numbers, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', numbers+'.'), LEN(numbers))
```

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above SQL is product specific.

Comment: Also, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(numbers, 1) = '0' THEN RIGHT(numbers, 2) ELSE numbers END AS FormattedNumbers
```

Answer (score 1):

why not using simple `substr()` ?

```
select case when substr(mycol,1,1)='0' then substr(mycol,2) else mycol end
from my table
```

you did not mention your DB so i assumed its oracle. This will work in any RDBMS.

Comment: The substr function is not ANSI SQL standard, or generally implemented. I.e. will work in several dbms, but not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `charindex` and `substring` methods to do string manipulation :)

```
select
    case when charindex('0', number) = 1
        then substring(number, 2, len(number))
        else number end
from (
    select '123' number
    union all
    select '023'
    union all 
    select '003'
    union all
    select '102'
) a
```